# Number of check bits for single-error-correcting binary linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

This is Exercise 23 of the [textbook "Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications" by Thomas W. Judson, 2016; Page 111](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20160809-print.pdf). Chapter 8 "Algebraic Coding Theory" mainly deals with **binary linear code**.

> **Exercise 23:** How many check positions are needed for a single error-correcting code with 20 information positions? With 32 information positions?

**My attempt:** Suppose that the number of check bits is $r$. Then we have 
$$2^r - 1 \ge r + 20$$ and $$2^r - 1 \ge r + 32$$ respectively. Therefore, $r$ are $5$ and $6$, respectively.

**However,** the (partial) answer given in the textbook (Page 331) is $r = 6$ for the case of 20 information bits:

> For 20 information positions, at least 6 check bits are needed to ensure an error-correcting code.

---

What is wrong with my argument?
And how to solve this problem (for both cases of 20 and 32 information bits)?

Comment: How is this related to linear algebra?

Comment: @marshalcraft I think the topic on [linear code (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) is closely related to linear algebra.

Comment: Ok, also if you don't find results here cryptography stack exchange may be well suited too, they are typically pretty good with abstract algebra and what not. Seems like paper is a good read, though maybe a little much if simply learning mathematics.

Comment: The answer in the book doesn't seem correct, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. Converting it into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in the book doesn't seem correct. $5$ parity bits can cover a block of $2^5-1=31$ bits, of which $31-5=26$ are information bits, so it should be more than enough to cover $20$ information bits. [This Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm) explains a popular linear code that achieves maximal efficiency in terms off the number of parity bits needed.

Let's explicitly build Hamming code that covers $20$ information bits.

We have a block of $25$ bits, numbered $b_1 \ldots b_{25}$. $5$ of those bits are parity bits, specifically $b_1, b_2, b_4, b_8, b_{16}$. The rest are information bits.

Expressions for the parity bits are:

\begin{array}{llcl} (1)& b_1 &=& b_3 \oplus b_5 \oplus \ldots \oplus b_{25} \\ (2)& b_2 &=& b_3 \oplus b_6 \oplus b_7 \oplus b_{10} \oplus b_{11} \oplus \ldots \oplus b_{22} \oplus b_{23} \\ (3)& b_4 &=& b_5 \oplus b_6 \oplus b_7 \oplus b_{12} \oplus b_{13} \oplus b_{14} \oplus b_{15} \oplus b_{20} \oplus b_{21} \oplus b_{22} \oplus b_{23} \\ (4)& b_8 &=& b_9 \oplus b_{10} \oplus \ldots \oplus b_{15} \oplus b_{24} \oplus b_{25} \\ (5)& b_{16} &=& b_{17} \oplus b_{18} \oplus \ldots \oplus b_{25} \end{array}

It is easy to see that each bit participates in a unique subset of these expressions. Specifically, bit $b_k$ participates in line $i$ iff the $i$th digit in the binary representation of $k$ is $1$.

Now if we have a possibly corrupt block $b'_1 \ldots b'_{25}$ where exactly one $b'_i$ is different from $b_i$, some of the equalities above will not hold. If we write down $0$ for each equality that holds and $1$ for each one that doesn't, we get exactly the number of the flipped bit, in binary. If all hold, there is no error.